# Duvida Dialog + SelectOneMenu JSF

Tags: java, jsf, mvc, spring

Ola, estou tentando abrir um dialog com um selectonemenu, dependendo do que o usuario selecionar. Meu SelectOneMenu esta assim

```
<p:column headerText="Mecânica">
                    <h:commandButton>
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanica}"
                            id="mecanica" onchange="PF('cadastraMecanica').show();"
                            rendered="#{document.type == 'Pergunta'}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a mecânica"
                                noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </p:column>
```

E Meu dialog esta assim

```
<h:form id="cadastraMecanica">
            <p:dialog style="text-align: center" header="Cadastrar Mecânica"
                widgetVar="cadastraMecanica" resizable="false" modal="true"
                width="1050" height="630">

                <p:outputPanel rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanica == 'QUIZ'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoQuiz.xhtml" />
                </p:outputPanel>

                <p:outputPanel
                    rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanica == 'VERDADEIROFALSO'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoVerdadeiroFalso.xhtml" />
                </p:outputPanel>

                <p:outputPanel
                    rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanica == 'DESCRITIVA'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoDescritiva.xhtml" />
                </p:outputPanel>

                <p:outputPanel
                    rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanica == 'ASSOCIACAO'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoAssociacao.xhtml" />
                </p:outputPanel>

                <p:outputPanel
                    rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanica == 'ARRASTASOLTA'}">
                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoArrastaSolta.xhtml" />
                </p:outputPanel>

            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

Minha duvida esta em como abrir corretamente o dialog, com o include correto do arquivo. Reparem que dependendo do que for selecionado ele faz um include diferente, porem nao estou conseguindo resgatar o valor selecionado pelo usuario para fazer a validação no dialog. Alguem pra dar um help?

Atualizando

Refatorei o codigo para tentar abrir o include correto, porem sem sucesso, segue a refatoração

```
<p:column headerText="Mecânica" style="text-align: center">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu id="mecanicas"
                                        value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicaSelecionada}"
                                        required="true" widgetVar="sel"
                                        onchange="PF('modalMecanica').show(); getMecanicaSelecionada()"
                                        rendered="#{document.type == 'Pergunta'}">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a mecânica" itemValue=""
                                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicas}"
                                            var="mecanica" id="mecanica" itemValue="#{mecanica.nome}"
                                            rendered="#{mecanica.nome != 'IMAGEM RESPOSTA'}"
                                            itemLabel="#{mecanica.nome}" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:column>
```

Aqui o dialog

```
    <h:form id="modalMecanica">
                            <p:dialog style="text-align: center" header="Cadastrar Mecânica"
                                widgetVar="modalMecanica" resizable="false" modal="true"
                                width="1050" height="630">
                                <p:outputPanel
                                    rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicaSelecionada == 'QUIZ'}">
                                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoQuiz.xhtml" />
                                </p:outputPanel>

                                <p:outputPanel
                                    rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicaSelecionada == 'VERDADEIRO FALSO'}">
                                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoVerdadeiroFalso.xhtml" />
                                </p:outputPanel>

                                <p:outputPanel
                                    rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicaSelecionada == 'DESCRITIVA'}">
                                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoDescritiva.xhtml" />
                                </p:outputPanel>

                                <p:outputPanel
                                    rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicaSelecionada == 'ASSOCIACAO'}">
                                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoAssociacao.xhtml" />
                                </p:outputPanel>

                                <p:outputPanel
                                    rendered="#{bancoPerguntasMBean.mecanicaSelecionada == 'ARRASTA SOLTA'}">
                                    <ui:include src="bancoPerguntasQuestaoArrastaSolta.xhtml" />
                                </p:outputPanel>
                            </p:dialog>
                        </h:form>
```

O dialog abre corretamente, porem vazio, nao esta realizando nenhum include. No bean criei um atributo que recebe o cara selecionado

```
private String mecanicaSelecionada;
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? O dialog não está abrindo...?

Comment: Ola Marlysson, editei a publicação com uma nova refatoração, porem nao consegui ainda fazer o include. O dialog abre normalmente, porem vazio. Consegue enchergar aonde posso estar errando?

Comment: Primeiro: suas páginas estão no mesmo diretório da que usa o dialog? Segundo: suas páginas incluídas devem conter a tag <ui:composition> sem os cabeçalhos html.. somente com o conteúdo..

Comment: As pagina estao no mesmo diretorio, e tambem estao com a tag <ui:composition>. Fiz o testo fazendo apenas o include sem o rendered,   abre normalmente os formularios. Ele esta se perdendo na hora da seleção do selectonemenu. Acredito que o bean nao esta resgatando o valor selecionado corretamente

Comment: Tenta colocar um <f:ajax process="@this" /> dentro do selectOneMenu.